# StreamingRenderer

Tags: polygon, coordinate-system, geotools

I have a problem in my code (Java Geotools). When I draw in my carte map a LineString ***sometimes*** when I run my program an errors apears and I don't understand what does it means.

**Error:**

> avr. 14, 2016 2:17:15 PM org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer fireErrorEvent
>   GRAVE: null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at sun.java2d.pipe.LoopPipe.fill(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.java2d.pipe.PixelToParallelogramConverter.fill(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.fill(Unknown Source)
>       at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StyledShapePainter.fillLiteShape(StyledShapePainter.java:710)
>       at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StyledShapePainter.paint(StyledShapePainter.java:264)
>       at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer$PaintShapeRequest.execute(StreamingRenderer.java:3344)
>       at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer$PainterThread.run(StreamingRenderer.java:3667)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

`

---

```
public static Layer addligne( ArrayList<Double> xPoints, ArrayList<Double> yPoints) throws SchemaException, ParseException {


        SimpleFeatureType lineType = DataUtilities.createType("LINE", "geom:LineString,name:String");

    final int N = xPoints.size();
    Coordinate[] coords = new Coordinate[N];
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {       
                double val_long=(double) xPoints.get(i);
                double val_lat=(double) yPoints.get(i);
                coords[i] = new Coordinate(val_long,val_lat); 
                 }

    GeometryFactory gFac = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(null);

       SimpleFeatureCollection col = FeatureCollections.newCollection("internal");

     ((DefaultFeatureCollection) col).add( SimpleFeatureBuilder.build( lineType, new Object[]{ gFac.createLineString(coords)}, null) );
    Style style =SLD.createLineStyle(Color.BLUE, 1.0f);
    Layer  layer = new FeatureLayer(col, style); 
  return layer;
}
```

Comment: can you add a link to the data you are drawing or the code that generates it

Comment: I suspect you might need to add the minimal amount of code to reproduce this problem for someone to be able to help you.

Comment: OK - what is in the array of points that causes the issue?

Comment: Here are some of the code when I use this method that causes the error*if (vect_inter.size()>200){
              try{
               Layer pLayer =Dessin.addLigne(vect1_inter,vect_inter);
               mapcontext.addLayer( pLayer); 
               StreamingRenderer render = new StreamingRenderer();
                       render.setMapContent(mapcontext);*